# VS Studio Debugger - Get (and watch) all instances of a type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

For a given stack frame, is there a quick a way (or an easy way to construct a way) to get all instances of a certain class/type for a given stack frame (stack and heap variables)? I would like to do this without any source code changes -- with additional functionality only coming from VS/VS-Debugger.

I'm envisioning this behavior would be quite useful when making changes to datatypes used throughout a large codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Heap Manager

From C++ runtime perspective, the heap manager allocates bytes via [HeapAlloc (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The signature is

```
LPVOID WINAPI HeapAlloc(
  _In_ HANDLE hHeap,
  _In_ DWORD  dwFlags,
  _In_ SIZE_T dwBytes
);
```

So if the heap manager allocates memory, it allocates a number of **bytes**, not memory for a **type**.

One helpful thing (not for Visual Studio though), at least for objects on the heap is to enable GFlags' "User mode stack trace database". With that enabled, it tracks allocations on the heap and associates it with a stack. That way, you still cannot see the type information, but at least find out in which method the memory was allocated. In small methods, you may find from the *dwBytes* information, which type it is - but still you have to do it manually.

### Debug Heap Manager

If you have a debug build, you can use [Debug Heap Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx) to help you keep track of allocations.

However, this is not completely without source code changes. You need to import the debug headers.

### Visual Studio 2013 Update 2

Since Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, there is a [memory diagnostic tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/21/native-memory-diagnostics-in-vs2015-preview.aspx), which even allows you to track the types of objects that are lost.

It does so by analyzing the PDBs and it fails for libraries where PDBs are not available.

[Screenshot http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-65-69/6813.8.png](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-65-69/6813.8.png)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/21/native-memory-diagnostics-in-vs2015-preview.aspx